# MySQL prepared statement execution plan

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I use MySQL 5.5 and groovy to execute a prepared statement query.

When I prepend the text of the prepared statement query with `EXPLAIN` and run it with the same parameters as the real query, how accurate is the execution plan reported back by MySQL in the returned rows - is it some generic plan or specific for these parameters?